# How do I pass arguments to `youtube-dl.exe`

Tags: youtube-dl, arguments

I have newly installed `youtube-dl.exe`

How do I pass arguments to it that normally appear as

> [www.example.com?A=1&B=2](http://www.example.com?A=1&B=2)

and also

**headers**
that appear as `-H`

Without change this gives an error:

`is not a valid URL` and
`B is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Also, I've saved headers as a text file with this form:
How can I attach it to youtube-dl.exe now ?

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: cs,sk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/
Origin: https://www.youtube.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: [GitHub - ytdl-org/youtube-dl: Command-line program to download videos from YouTube.com and other video sites](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What command did you execute to get the error?

Comment: [Youtube-dl Tutorial With Examples For Beginners - OSTechNix](https://ostechnix.com/youtube-dl-tutorial-with-examples-for-beginners/)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio `youtube-dl.exe http://www.example.com?A=1&B=2` It gives Requesting headers. And 'B' is not rcognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have gone through the manual but I cannot find the right place for `parameters` :-( Could you solove my simple case right here ?

Comment: quote the url: `youtube-dl "http://www.example.com?A=1&B=2"`